# How to search data by ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, search, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to search data by `ListView` data coming from a websevice..

Description:  if I enter **[abc]** in search `editview[searchText]` and if I click `serachbutton(buttonSearch)`, it must show all related data in `listview(listView)`

Ex: abc, abacd, abcderg etc. in this way...

This topic is new for me.

Here is my code. Please help me do it.

I have tried, but I was not able to figure out how to do this.

**worklistview.java**

```
    ArrayList<Patient> patientListArray;


 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workListview);
    objectAdapter = new WorkListAdapter(this, patientListArray);
    listView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);     
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());


        }
    }); 

WorkListAdapter.java

public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {



        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (!patientListArray.isEmpty()){
                clear();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < patientListArray.size(); i++) {
                if(patientListArray.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                    add(patientListArray.get(i));
                }
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void add(Patient patient) {


        }

        private void clear() {


        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            return null;
        }
    };  

    return myFilter;
}
```

Comment: What is `quickAction.show(v)`

Comment: @spk that is a dialog.. when i click button dialog will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Graphically, you need a layout with an EditText (TextWatcher) and a listview. Then, the adapter of your listview will be always listening the changes on your TextWatcher using a filter ( dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString()); )

More details [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-edittext-filter.html)

Good luck.